# What is the purpose of Action Bar?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

I'm new to Android development, but I'm just curious... Why should we implement Action Bar? Do there exist Android devices without Menu button?

I've asked a few people (not developers) about their thoughts about Action Bar. Most of them treated it as a "title bar". Some of them noticed that there is sometimes a "search" button. Almost nobody know what "up" button is and what is the difference between "up" and "back" buttons. If they want more options, they tap "Menu" button (the one on phone, not on Action Bar).

To be honest - I'm an Android phone user for a long time but... I found out the purpose of Action Bar (and what "up" button is) when I was reading Android documentation...

So, should we implement Action Bar? Do people want it and use it? Do they know "how"?

Comment: The Action Bar is both pretty awesome, and pretty central to the "new" Android. Google goes into pretty good detail [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). There is a reason ActionBarSherlock is/was an extremely popular library. There is also a reason why you now get ActionBarCompat with Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

> Why should we implement Action Bar?

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), the action bar "provides several key functions:

- Makes important actions prominent and accessible in a predictable way (such as New or Search).
- Supports consistent navigation and view switching within apps.
- Reduces clutter by providing an action overflow for rarely used actions.
- Provides a dedicated space for giving your app an identity."

> Do there exist Android devices without Menu button?

Yes, there are devices that do not have a MENU button. This has nothing much to do with whether or not you should consider an action bar.

> If they want more options, they tap "Menu" button (the one on phone, not on Action Bar).

That is only possible on devices that have a MENU button. Many do not, particularly tablets. The overflow affordance ("...") in the action bar brings up the overflow "menu", just as the MENU button does.

> So, should we implement Action Bar?

Most conventional UI apps should, IMHO. Games usually do not. Also, not every activity within an app would need an action bar (e.g., in a video player, the player activity itself might not have an action bar, while other activities in the app do).

Answer (score 0):

Not to get into too much detail.
Use the actionbar so your app looks and feels the same on new and old phones.

I'll try to explain why you should implement the actionbar.  One goal of the support library is to increase user demand for new phones by showing existing users cool functions available on new android phones.  In theory the old phone users will buy new phones to get the features.  The up button is cool because you can start screen two of your app with an intent filter maybe from an email preview and there is the up button to get screen one of your app where the back button takes you back to the email.